# adding different line into existing scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on adding different average line (using different color) for depression rate for different policy group into existing scatter plot. For example, if i want to add the depression average line for no limited group.

This is my dataset that screenshoot randomly:

[image]

my code right is like this:

```
ggplot(covid_depression_2020_policy, aes(x = Location, y = Depression.2020, color = `Large Gatherings Ban`)) + 
  geom_point(alpha=0.8)
```

Comment: FYI, you pasted twice the data instead of your chart.

Comment: I think you can find the answer to this with a little research effort. I will provide the answer below but I highly recommend reading any introduction to ggplot2 tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

**Line of Best Fit using geom_smooth()**

To add average lines into a ggplot's scatter plot, you can use `geom_smooth()`, which gives "smoothed conditional means" or line of best fit per conditions given.

```r
ggplot(covid_depression_2020_policy, 
    aes(x = Location, y = Depression.2020, color = `Large Gatherings Ban`)) + 
    geom_point(alpha=0.8) +
    geom_smooth()
```

A different colored line will be created for each "Large Gatherings Ban" group because of the `` color = `Large Gatherings Ban` `` argument specified inside `ggplot()`'s aesthetics (i.e., `aes(...)`).

If you want a line only for `Large Gatherings Ban == "No Limit"`, you can specify that in the data for `geom_smooth()`, like this:

```r
geom_smooth(data = dplyr::filter(covid_depression_2020_policy, `Large Gatherings Ban` == "No Limit"))
```

`dplyr::filter()` is used to subset the rows in the dataset such that only the column condition(s) are met.

Depending on how you're trying to visualize the data, some common arguments used in `geom_smooth(...)` includes `method = lm` (for a straight line of best fit) or `se = FALSE` (to remove the default confidence interval ribbon). Run `?ggplot2::geom_smooth()` to see more options.

**Horizontal Average Line using geom_hline()**

You may want to create an average line that doesn't have a slope because your "Location" is a nominal categorical variable without meaningful order. Thus, having a slope here doesn't make sense. In this case, you may want to use `geom_hline()` to plot a horizontal line for each "Large Gatherings Ban" group.

```r
ggplot(covid_depression_2020_policy, 
    aes(x = Location, y = Depression.2020, color = `Large Gatherings Ban`)) + 
    geom_point(alpha=0.8) +
    geom_hline( 
        data = dplyr::filter(covid_depression_2020_policy, `Large Gatherings Ban` == "No Limit"),
        aes(yintercept = mean(Depression.2020), color = `Large Gatherings Ban`)) + 
    geom_hline( 
        data = dplyr::filter(covid_depression_2020_policy, `Large Gatherings Ban` == ">50 Prohibited"),
        aes(yintercept = mean(Depression.2020), color = `Large Gatherings Ban`))
```

`geom_hline(...)` only makes one line, so you will have to add it for each "Large Gatherings Ban" group.

[See here for a ggplot2 tutorial.](http://r-statistics.co/Complete-Ggplot2-Tutorial-Part1-With-R-Code.html)